# Returning as integer when a float is expected in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, math

Hello I have code that looks like this

```
 float ordered = 0;
 float completed = 0;
        if (jod.Components != null)
        {
            int qty = jod.comp_qty == null ? 0 : (int)jod.comp_qty;
            CompHasParts chp = jod.Components.CHP.Where(x => x.PartID == Model.ID).FirstOrDefault();
            if (chp != null && chp.PartID == Model.ID)
            {
                ordered += (float)Math.Ceiling(chp.qty * qty);
            }
         }
```

chp.qty = 1.25 and qty = 10. But this currently returns 13 instead of 12.5

Why is this?

Comment: That's how Math.Ceiling works.

Comment: `Math.Ceiling()` returns a whole number. `Math.Ceiling(12.5)` is `13.0`.

Comment: Ahh I see, Thanks

Comment: What did you think Ceiling did?

Comment: @Rob I wasn't sure, it wasn't my code just not sure why the other person put that in when that's not what we wanted